# Does Constituency Parse annotator include the full Deparse?

Tags: stanford-nlp

From the Constituency parse documentation it seems obvious you can also get a dependency parse from the "parse" annotator. (Kind of like a bonus!) Is the dependency parse annotation produced by the constituency "parse" annotator the same output as the annotation produced by the "deparse" annotator?

In other words, if you run the constituency parse annotator, is it redundant to also run the "deparse" step?

I already use the dependency parser and want to start using the constituency parser as well. I don't want to double up on the parsers if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you run the constituency parser there is a rule based process that will create a dependency parse structure based on the constituency parse, so yes you will automatically get a dependency parse for a sentence. You only need to run the `parse` annotator if you want both types of parses.

It is important to note that this won't necessarily be the same dependency parse that the neural model will generate. So in case 1 you create a statistical constituency parse, and then with rules convert that to a dependency parse. In case 2 you are using a neural model to only generate a dependency parse. I am sure quite regularly these parses are not identical.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. So I'm assuming the neural parse will be "mostly better."